# The result of O(f(n)) - O(f(n))

Tags: asymptotics, computer-science, computational-complexity

My question is in the field of the big-O-notation and complexity/asymptotic functions:

Probably something that I'm missing, but I've couldn't find any well explained solution for the following:
What would be the result of:

(1) $O(f(n))-O(f(n))$?

Also, is the solution of $O(f(n))+O(f(n))$ is based on the same idea/rules of (1)

Comment: What does "-" mean in this context?

Comment: @user127.0.0.1 a minus sign

Comment: Of course, but again: what does the minus-sign mean in this context?

Comment: @user127.0.0.1 - oh... I'm sorry. I'm into that so much time that it seems obvious for me that I'm talking about the big-O-notation and complexity or asymptotic functions. Let me edit that...

Comment: @ZivLevy There's a subtle point here that you might be missing: $O(f(n))$ isn't a _function_, it's a _set_ (specifically, a set of functions) - and there isn't a natural definition of $A-B$ where $A$ and $B$ are sets.  If you want to understand the set $S=\{a-b|a\in O(f(n)), b\in O(f(n))\}$ (in other words, the set of all possible differences of two functions each of which is in $O(f(n))$) then you should make that more explicit in the question.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki - accepted. Again, sorry, I'm new to this topic

Answer (score 1):

The big-O classes are closed under addition/subtraction of functions, which is what I assume you mean (i.e. if two functions $g$ and $h$ are both $O(n^2)$ say, then so is $g+h$ and $g-h$ in general).

Answer (score 1):

Typically in math, $O(f(n))$ is taken to be a set of functions.  In this context, $O(f(n))-O(f(n))$ would be set-difference, which would obviously be $\emptyset$.

I feel like what you really meant to ask was, "If $f,g \in  $O(h)$, is f-g \in O(h)$?"  The answer is yes, which is simple to show:

$$f \le M*h \;\text{and}\; g \le N*h$$
$$f-g \le (M-N)*h$$

Note that if we change $O$ to $\Theta$, the answer is 'no,' since $f-g = 0$ when $g=f$